# Исключить символ на определенной позиции с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Есть строка значения, например anytext{3}text, которая проходит по регулярному выражению `^.+|{\d}.+$`.

У меня есть потребность модифицировать выражение таким образом, что если в проверяемом значении перед `{\d}` из предыдущего выражения находится символ `@` то такое значение не должно проходить проверку.

Я написал следующее выражение для этой цели: `^(.+[^@]|){\d}(.+)$`
Но работает не так как я ожидал, например, следующие значения ожидаемо **проходят** проверку успешно:

```
anytext{3}text
{3}text
@ {3}text //Тут между @ и {3} пробел, что допустимо
@anytext{3}text
@@anytext{3}text@
anyte@xt{3}text
```

И так-же ожидаемо следующие значения **не** проходят проверку:

```
anytext@{3}text
@{3}text
```

Но в тоже время я ожидаю, что следующее значение успешно пройдет проверку, чего не происходит:

```
a{3}text
```

Как написать выражение, которое бы пропускало любые значения которые обязательно содержат `{\d}` и может соержать любые символы в любом количестве перед и после значения `{\d}`, кроме случая, когда непосредственно перед `{\d}` находится символ `@`?

Comment: вы не думаете, что ветка ^.+$ пропустит любое не пустое выражение. И что вы пишите после вертикальной черты имеет мало значения

Comment: Да, поэтому по тексту я изменяю выражение и оно становится: ^(.+[^@]|){\d}(.+)$ и  тут .+ в скобках, что решает эту проблему. Предполагается любое количество символов, кроме @ непосредственно перед {\d}. И вроде бы работает, но не прохоит если перед {\d} просто один любой символ

Comment: `^.*[^@]{\d}.*$` https://regex101.com/r/ItQJJp/1

Comment: @splash58 Потрясающе это работает. Спасибо большое! А почему не срабатывает вслучае с ```.+```?

Comment: Потому что плюс говорит о том что должен идти любой символ хотя бы один раз.